# Splash Screen not working in kitkat and lower api level in android

Tags: android, splash-screen

I'm using splash screen in my android app. It working fine with lollipop and higher versions but not working with kitkat and lower versions.
Issue is in menifest.xml but i'm unable to fix it.

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"

    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".SplashScreenActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
            android:value="@string/facebook_app_id" />

        <intent-filter>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

---

SplashScreenActivity.java

public class SplashScreenActivity extends Activity {

```
public void onAttachedToWindow() {
    super.onAttachedToWindow();
    Window window = getWindow();
    window.setFormat(PixelFormat.RGBA_8888);
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);

    StartAnimations();
    Thread background = new Thread() {
        public void run() {

            try {
                // Thread will sleep for 5 seconds
                sleep(3*1000);

                // After 5 seconds redirect to another intent
                Intent i=new Intent(getBaseContext(),MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);

                //Remove activity
                finish();

            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
        }
    };

    // start thread
    background.start();



}

private void StartAnimations() {

    Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.alpha);
    anim.reset();
    LinearLayout l=(LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.lin_lay);
    l.clearAnimation();
    l.startAnimation(anim);

    anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.translate);
    anim.reset();
    ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.logo);
    iv.clearAnimation();
    iv.startAnimation(anim);

}
```

}

---

In res/anim/alpha.xml

alpha.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<alpha
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromAlpha="0.0"
    android:toAlpha="1.0"
    android:duration="3000" />
```

Comment: show the code, the Activity code

Comment: i think No prolem in  menifest.xml file...can you post SplashScreenActivity java code.

Comment: Share your java code and xml also.

Comment: As all suggested share your activity code

Comment: Checkout java code below

Answer (score 1):

There is my SplashScreen. It works for android 4.1 and higher.

SplashScreen.java

```
public class SplashScreen extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splashscreen_layout);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {

        super.onStart();


        // load your stuff here ...


        Intent intent = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, YourHomeActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();

    }
}
```

res/layout/splashscreen_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
    tools:context=".SplashScreen"
    android:theme="@style/SplashTheme">

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

add on your res/values/styles.xml

```
<style name="SplashTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splashscreen_drawable</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
</style>
```

res/drawable/splashscreen_drawable.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@color/colorPrimary"/>

    <item>
        <bitmap
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/your_icon" />
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

and my AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application

        [...]

        >
        <activity
            android:name="com.your.package.app.SplashScreen"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/SplashTheme">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        [...]
```

It looks at this on:

- 4.1 (api 16): [SplashScreen 4.1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vXH1a.png)
- 6.0 (api 23): [SplashScreen 6.0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fwQku.png)